# How do I chain vert and street tricks in Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 1/2/HD?

Tags: xbox-live-arcade, tony-hawks-pro-skater-hd

I've never really played the first two "Tony Hawk's Pro Skater" games - I've only began to obsessively play it from the third game onward, but Tony Hawk's Pro Skater HD brought me back to the first two games. So, it might be a newbie question, but here goes: is it possible to chain together street and vert tricks without using the Revert which was added in THPS3?

Comment: I haven't played the new release, but have you tried a manual? Can't remember if it was possible in the first two games or not, but it should be up and down ( or down and up) on the control stick to go into a manual.

Comment: I have. Unless something in my timing is off, it just ends the combo and starts a manual.

Comment: You have to jump into a manual to keep the combo going. That is one of the only things I remember from back then.

Comment: so... when coming down from the pipe - jumping + manual? Doesn't have to do a No Comply for that?

Comment: In the first two games, it was practically impossible to continue your combo off of a vert ramp (a `revert`) unless you could somehow land in a grind.  But since you don't level off, you couldn't do it.  You might be able to if you shot off the ramp at a close-to-horizontal angle toward a rail/ledge, I don't think that ever worked though.

Comment: ok, the jump+manual doesn't really work. @JeffMercado - "It's impossible" is a legit answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back in Tony Hawk Proskater 1(original game, not hd), you were unable to perform a manual. In the second game, they added the manual, but you are still unable to manual after performing a tick from a pipe. Even if you pressed down/up, up/down before landing off a pipe, you cannot combo  that trick. Street tricks/rails can be chained with manuals by pressing up/down, down/up as mentioned in the other answer.

I have played all three games mentioned and I am also finding inconsistencies with chaining using manuals in the updated HD game. It seems as though the HD re-make is not polished enough to consistently record a manual after performing excessive grinds/street tricks. Also, it is impossible to chain a manual to a vert trick in THPS HD, unless you buy the Revert DLC Pack, and then it is possible to chain the tricks using a revert move.

Answer (score 2):

Revert was given free in a patch before the DLC was released. You do not need to buy the DLC revert pack in order to receive the code adding revert to the game.